# Searching related table with a single attribute in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables one checks and truck

this is their structure:

```
 table truck : has truckid, reg_no, truck_category
 table check : has truck_id(fkey from truck table), checkid....
```

What am trying to achieve is while using the truck id in table check model display tabletruck details(reg_no, truck_category)

This is the relationship in tblcheck model

```
 public function getTruck()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TblTrucks::className(), ['id' => 'truck_id']);
}
```

So i have done a search model with:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'ref_no','done_by', 'done_at'], 'integer'],
        [['checks_fails', 'done_on','truck_id'], 'safe'], 
    ];
}

  public function search($params)
{
    $query = Tblchecks::find();
    // add conditions that should always apply here
    $query->joinWith('truck');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'ref_no' => $this->ref_no,
        'check_has' => $this->check_has,
        'done_by' => $this->done_by,
        'done_at' => $this->done_at,
        'done_on' => $this->done_on,
    ]);

     // here am filtering with the same truck_id
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'truck.company', $this->truck_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'truck.regno', $this->truck_id]);


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

So in my grid i have

```
 [
        'attribute' => 'truck_id',
        'width'=>'310px',
        'value'=>'truck.company',
],
 [
        'attribute' => 'truck_id',
        'header' => 'Truck number',
        'value'=>'truck.regno',
 ]
```

The above does not filter my grid, How do i go about filtering the grid using one attribute which is a foreign key to display related items

Comment: The  truck.company  and truck.regno are from truck or from check table? ..

Comment: they are from truck table but the search model is happening in the check table

Comment: I don't understand  you have the two column in both the tables? ..

Comment: No i dont have similar columns in both tables.. The way i have designed the databse is: I have two tables(tble check and table truck). .............Table truck has(truck id(pkey), regno, truck category).. ...........Table check has(truckid(fkey from table truck).,............................................What am hoping to achieve is to use table check and display records from table truck as they are related by truck id

Comment: #scais the fields truck.company and truck.regno are the actual columns (company and regno) but truck is the name of the relationship thats why i had tried using truck.company...

Comment: I have posted answer hope is useful

Comment: I see the logic thanks it also works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this way

in model  ( tblcheck model in your case)  for each field youn need  in relation  build a getter function

```
public function getTruck()
{
  return $this->hasOne(TblTrucks::className(), ['id' => 'truck_id']);
}


// Getter for truck.company   
// this  from the relation above (truck) return th field company
public function getTruck_company() {
    return $this->truck->company;
}
```

in search model

```
    // filter by company  from Tblcheck
        $query->joinWith(['truck' => function ($q) {
            $q->where( truck_tabale_name.company LIKE "%' . $this->truck_company . '%"' );
        }]);
```

and in grid view  .. simply use the getter

```
[
    'attribute' => 'truck_company',
    'width'=>'310px',
],
```